# Entity Framework : many to many relationship , Insert and update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a news entity and I get the news based on their NewsID. then I defined a new entity , a Group and I want to get the news based on their Group ID. I tried to handle this (many to many) relationships using [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First)by using code first approach.

[image]

so in my context I added :

```
 public class Groupnews : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Group> Group { get; set; }
        public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }

        public Groupnews()
            : base("MyDb")
        {
        }

        public int NewsID { get; set; }
    }

this.HasMany(t => t.News)
    .WithMany(t => t.Groups)
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("GroupNews");
            m.MapLeftKey("GroupID");
            m.MapRightKey("NewsID");
        });
```

now I can get the news based on Their GroupID using this approach. but the problem is in insertign new News and updating.For that I need to save NewsID and GroupId in GroupNews table. for doing this . in News model i defined :

```
    public virtual ICollection<Group> RelatedGroups { get; set; }

    public News()
    {
        RelatedGroups = new List<Group>();
    }
```

and the same for group :

```
    public virtual ICollection<News> RelatedNews { get; set; }
    public Group()
    {
        RelatedNews = new List<News>();
     }
```

In my news controller I add :

```
            Group group = new Group();
            group.RelatedNews.Add(news);
```

[image]

but nothing is updated and the NewsID is not adding to my GroupNews table .

Answer (score 11):

You should not define GroupNews separately. Meaning, you should not have a `GroupNews` class defined in your project. You have to do CRUD operations using independent associations (a list of `News` in `Group` class and a list of `Group` in your `News` class). Here's what your classes should look like:

```
public class Group
{
    ...
    public Group()
    {
         this.News = new List<News>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News {get;set;}
}

public class News
{
    ...
    public News()
    {
         this.Group = new List<Group>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `myGroup.News.Add(myNewsItem)` or `myNews.Groups.Add(myGroup)`. Entity Framework will handle the insertion automatically. Notice you should use `virtual` keyword if you want to enable lazy loading for your associations.

Comment: I wrote groupnews.Add(NewsID) and the  Error 'MeetingBoard.DAL.MeetingBoardContext.Groupnews' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'MeetingBoard.DAL.MeetingBoardContext.Groupnews' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please refer to my answer. I have stated that there's no need to define `GroupNews` class. You should use many-to-many relationships using only related properties in your `Group` and `News`  classes.

Comment: I did as you said  (group.RelatedNews.Add(news)) but it doesn't insert anything to the GroupNews table

Comment: Update your question with your new code based on my answer so we can know what your current situation is.

Comment: I think the correct mapping would be `this.HasMany(t => t.RelatedNews).WithMany(t => t.RelatedGroups)`

Comment: I defined GroupNews model and solved the problem. this way you mentioned seems not good for projects that has so many complicated relations. defining a new model seems more classified and easily usable/readable later on.

Comment: Well, your architecture seems smelly IMO. This is the recommended approach by ADO.Net team as you can see in their tutorials. It has the benefit to let you look at your model in OOP way. We have a solution with 200+ tables and complicated relationships (including various many-to-many) and haven't had any problems in architecture.